# Create a new row based on the difference of previous rows in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

I have extracted a html table using `rvest` and received a dataframe like this:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~ward,               ~patient_count, ~date,
  "ICU",                10,            "2021-01-01",
  "of which ventilated", 6,            "2021-01-01",
  "other",               4,            "2021-01-01", 
  "ICU",                 8,            "2021-01-02",
  "of which ventilated", 2,            "2021-01-02",
  "other",               4,            "2021-01-02", 
)
```

I'm unhappy with this data layout. My first thought was to try to get something like this:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~ward,               ~patient_count, ~ventilated, ~date,
  "ICU",                 4,            FALSE,       "2021-01-01",
  "ICU",                 6,            TRUE,        "2021-01-01",
  "other",               4,            FALSE,       "2021-01-01",
  "ICU",                 6,            FALSE,       "2021-01-02",
  "ICU",                 2,            TRUE,        "2021-01-02",
  "other",               4,            FALSE,       "2021-01-02",
)
```

I tried setting the `ventilated` tag like this:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    ventilated = case_when(ward == "of which ventilated" ~ TRUE,
                           ward != "of which ventilated" ~ FALSE)
  )
```

However, I'm not quite sure what's the best way to get the numbers right.

Comment: I believe you'd be better off pivoting the data to wider with one row per date, then manipulating the names and value of the columns will be trivial, and you might pivot them back to longer if you really want to

Answer (score 1):

Using `case_when` similarly,(I made it as `patient_count_2`)

I wonder if there's a more detailed rule to change `patient_count`. Thanks to @r2evans, to consider robust way, if format of data can be different with the `data` you provided? Or always like `ICU` then `of which ventilated`?

```
data %>%
  mutate(patient_count_2 = case_when(
    lead(ward) == "of which ventilated" ~ patient_count - lead(patient_count),
    TRUE ~ patient_count
  ),
  ventilated = (ward == "of which ventilated"), 
  ward = ifelse(ward == "of which ventilated", "ICU", ward)
  )


  ward  patient_count date       patient_count_2 ventilated
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                <dbl> <lgl>     
1 ICU              10 2021-01-01               4 FALSE     
2 ICU               6 2021-01-01               6 TRUE      
3 other             4 2021-01-01               4 FALSE     
4 ICU               8 2021-01-02               6 FALSE     
5 ICU               2 2021-01-02               2 TRUE      
6 other             4 2021-01-02               4 FALSE
```

Comment: The use of `lead(.)` seems fragile on the order of rows, is there a way you can make it more robust to that? (It would also seem relevant to `group_by(date)` or such.)

Comment: @r2evans I didn't notice that. Thanks a lot. I'll try robust way :D.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try pivoting the data:

```
library(tidyr)

data <- tribble(
   ~ward,               ~patient_count, ~date,
   "ICU",                10,            "2021-01-01",
   "of which ventilated", 6,            "2021-01-01",
   "other",               4,            "2021-01-01", 
   "ICU",                 8,            "2021-01-02",
   "of which ventilated", 2,            "2021-01-02",
   "other",               4,            "2021-01-02", 
)

pivot_wider(data, names_from = "ward", values_from = "patient_count")


# A tibble: 2 × 4
  date         ICU `of which ventilated` other
  <chr>      <dbl>                 <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-01-01    10                     6     4
2 2021-01-02     8                     2     4
```